# Assign id for dynamically created HTML elements

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have been currently working on web application and I had the following issues. I am working in spring mvc

1. Am creating the text boxes dynamically based on the input and using the for loop.
   Here is the problem is with the ids

   `for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    <input type="text" id="myText"+i/>     Throwing compiler error`

I tried with many options like
`id = "'myText'+i" and "'myText'+i"` nothing worked for me. Though these are not throwing any errors but not working when I get the  text from these boxes as like below:

```
doc.getElemByID("") -> Throwing null over here. Because label ids are not generating properly. I came to know after debugging. May I know why this is not working?
```

2. I have tried with `<c:foreach>` inside  and its working fine. But here I have a problem. That is
   `<c:foreach begin ="0" end ="5" var="x"> ...`

But here I am determining the end value based on the text field.
That is `var num = getText();`

And I am planning to use this in `c:foreach` loop. But it is not working. I mean the value is not reflecting in foreach loop.

Please help me how can I use the Script variable inside JSTL tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to use a javascript variable inside a JSTL Tag, because JSTL is executed in server side, and javascript in client side (JSTL tag is executed before getting your JavaScript value). so try to calculate the end value in your controller and put him to the model or use a scriptlet in your JSP page:

```
<%
  int num = 10;// your code
%>

<c:foreach begin ="0" end ="${num}" var="x">
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for clarifying and for suggestions